# Twitter Bootstrap .popover() function not working in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to start using Twitter Bootstrap for Rails. The `popover()` function is not working at all. Nothing happens.

`layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-buttons.js"       %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-twipsy.js" %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag "http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap-popover.js" %>
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
 <script>
 $(function () {
     $("a[rel=popover]")
     .popover({
        offset: 10
     })
     .click(function(e) { 
            e.preventDefault()
     })
  });
 </script> 
 </head>
 <body>
 <%= yield %>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is my a part of my `views/test/test.htlm.erb`:

```
<li>
    <a data-placement="below" 
       class="btn danger span2" 
       data-content="This is a test" 
       href="#"        
       rel="popover">+ Test</a>
</li>
```

Part of my Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.3'
gem 'jruby-openssl'
gem 'json'
 group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    gem 'jquery-rails'
 end
```

I also tried to copy/paste the `twipsy.js` and `popover.js` in my `application.js` file and to call it in my layouts/application.html.erb with:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag    "application" %>
```

What am I missing? Any ideas?

Comment: is jQuery also included on your page?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your selector you're using:

```
$("a[rel=popover]")
```

That jQuery selector matches the entire `rel` attribute, and according to a [Bootstrap bug report](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/856), Rails adds additional attributes to the `rel` tag, like `nofollow`.

Try using this selector instead:

```
$("a[rel*=popover]")
```

Comment: Hi Jared, Tks for your response. Actually the $("a[rel=popover]") is good working with rails. I had a mistake in my link to the jquery library. I replaced it by <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"> and it's working well