# How to use Twitter-Bootstrap hover popover with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am a newbie with rails, I want to use the Twitter-Bootstrap hover popover in my rails app.
I have the following part:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name, {:class => 'label'}%>&nbsp;
    <%= f.text_field :first_name ,{:class => 'span3',}%>
</div>
```

If the user hover on the `:first_name` label, a message appear telling him something. But I don't know where to put things in my app like the js files reference or the function.

I tried this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659890/twitter-bootstrap-popover-function-not-working-in-rails) and put the `javascript_include_tag` in the layout/application.html.erb

But seems that I don't know how to get it works. So I need a detailed description about how to use it.

Comment: What Rails version are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are [several](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails)* [Rails](https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails)* [Bootstrap](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails-bootstrap)* projects that you can use for integrating Bootstrap.

If you would rather do it manually, one option is to place the files (including any plugins you want to use, which in your case would be `bootstrap-tooltip.js` and `bootstrap-popover.js`) into `/vendor/assets/javascripts` and include them in your `application.js` like so:

```
//= require bootstrap-min.js
//= require bootstrap-tooltip.js
//= require bootstrap-popover.js
```

Do the same with the `bootstrap.css` CSS file by dropping it into `/vendor/assets/stylesheets` and including it in `/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` by adding this line below `*= require_self`:

```
*= require bootstrap
```

I personally prefer using the full `bootstrap.css` file instead of the minified `bootstrap-min` because I occasionally want to browse the source. Either way, when you deploy to production, the CSS will be minified by Rails automatically via the asset pipeline.

---

Once you have Bootstrap loaded in, you can use the following snippet to initialize the popover plugin on the element of your choice:

```
$('.label-with-popover').popover(placement: 'right') # Note: 'right' is default
```

You can place the above snippet at the bottom of your `application.js` but the recommended way is to place it in the .coffee file that is respective to the scaffold you are working with, for example `users.js.coffee`

And finally..

```
  <label class="label-with-popover"
         data-content="popover content"
         data-title="popover title">

  ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand those lines: Do the same with the CSS file by dropping it into /vendor/assets/stylesheets and including it in application.css via *= require bootstrap

Comment: and where shall I put this` $('.label-with-popover').popover(placement: 'right')`

Comment: I edited the post to elaborate on the instructions. Let me know if you have any other questions; it was only a few months ago that I was still learning where things of this nature should reside so I remember it fondly.

Comment: Thanks, I followed every step but it doesn't work, and don't know why??

Comment: Check if the include tags are showing up in your generated source. If they are, verify by opening the files, the paths should look like this: `http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/bootstrap-popover.js` (alternatively use the Chrome Inspector to check if the necessary files all load.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. The files appear when opening them from the path. But I wonder where is the class `label-with-popover`, shall i found it in a css file?? Also do you mean that I have to inclued java_script_includetags of bootstrap-tooltip.js and bootstrap-popover.js and bootstrap.css in the layout/application.html.erb head tag.

Comment: The class name can be anything you want, it's just a [jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Looking at the snippet you posted, you might to change it to `.label` or use @Chris Barretto's example and use `$("[data-pop-over]")`

Comment: ok I got that but do you mean that I have to inclued java_script_includetags of bootstrap-tooltip.js and bootstrap-popover.js and bootstrap.css in the layout/application.html.erb head tag.

Comment: If all the JavaScript files are opening from the path, then you have nothing to worry about, i.e. they are loading correctly. You do not need to include the bootstrap files individually in your `application.html.erb` because you already listed them in `application.js`. The benefit if doing it this way is you utilize the Rails Asset Pipeline which will merge and minify your JavaScript when you deploy your project.

Comment: If you want to share your Gtalk or Skype I can help you via chat. It sounds like your files are loading so I'm not really sure what the problem is, but Chrome's JavaScript Console is very helpful for stuff like this.

Comment: in rails 4, ruby 2.0.0 it works with this code 
 '$("[data-pop-over]").popover({placement: 'right'});'
Generates error with 
 '('.label-with-popover').popover(placement: 'right');'

Answer (score 4):

I added a popover helper using something like:

```
module PopoverHelper
  def popover(model_name, attribute)
    i18n_base = "simple_form.popovers.#{model_name.downcase}.#{attribute}"

    content_tag(:i, '', class: "icon-question-sign",
                        id: "#{attribute}_help",
                        title: I18n.t("#{i18n_base}.title"),
                        data: {
                            # don't use popover as it conflicts with the actual pop-over thingy
                            pop_over: true,
                            content: I18n.t("#{i18n_base}.text")
                        })
  end
end
```

In your view you can run the js:

```
$("[data-pop-over]").popover({placement: 'right'});
```

Along with your helper:

```
= popover(:model, :attribute)
```

This is provided that you have bootstrap already loaded as well as jquery. You can sub out the i18n with hard-coded text if you wish.